# Django UNIQUE constraint failed: players_comment.user_id

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to post comment but it's not getting posted, rather this error is appearing `UNIQUE constraint failed: players_comment.user_id`. I don't know why this error is occuring.

My forms.py:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body', 'transfernews')
```

My models.py :

```
class Transfernews(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    player_image = models.CharField(max_length=2083)
    player_description = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transfernews = models.ForeignKey(Transfernews, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.transfernews.player_name, self.user.username)
```

My views.py:

```
def transfer_targets(request):
    transfernews = Transfernews.objects.all()
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
        new_comment.user = request.user
        new_comment.save()
        return redirect('transfernews/')
    return render(request, 'transfernews.html', {'transfernews': transfernews, 'form': form})
```

My transfernews.html:

```
{% for transfer in transfernews %}
  {% if not transfer.comments.all %}
    No comments Yet...
{% else %}
{% for comment in transfer.comments.all %}
    <strong>
        {{ comment.user.username }} - {{ comment.date_added }}
    </strong>
    <br/>
    {{ comment.body }}
    <br/><br/>

{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
<hr>
<div>Comment and let us know your thoughts</div>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm shadow-none" type="submit">Post comment</button>
    
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm ml-1 shadow-none" type="button">Cancel</button>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: SInce you use a `OneToOneField`, this means that each user can *at most* have one `Comment`.

Comment: which shouldn't be the case, now how can I fix this bro? Should I change it to `OneToMany` field?

Comment: You should read the docs, bro. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In models.py, in the comment class, change

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

to

```
user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

One to one works both ways, user's allowed to only have one comment and a comment can belong to only one user. By changing to one to many via foreignkey you'll preserve the latter and get rid of the former constraint.